# How to extrude all edges 1cm from center point?

Tags: modeling

How can you extrude all these edges 1 cm away from the center point, thus creating a rectangle 1 cm larger in all directions?

[image]

Blend file here also, the desired edges are already selected:
[.Blend file](http://www.mediafire.com/file/okd3v2d9ko36xu4/Room.blend)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. With the loop selected, press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> to scale it
   along the normals.
2. Press <kbd>S</kbd> again to activate `Even Thickness`, so you define the actual width of the border instead of the corner edges' length.
3. Enter `-.01` to get a border of 1cm width.

The edges don't provide normals to scale along, so the adjacent faces' normals are used, which are pointing inwards. This is why you have to enter a negative distance.

Comment: I tried that now, but i believe it scaled the edges .01 (1 percent) bigger. It didn't move each individual edge 1cm further from the inner edges.

Comment: did u apply scale before atl+s

Comment: Yes, the scale and rotation was applied, i confirmed it also from the side panel where it says scale and so on.

Comment: Change the pivot from 3d cursor to individual origins

Comment: You're right. This method creates a diagonal edge with a distance of 1cm, when the Y-position is the same. You have to press S after Alt+S to enable the `Even Thickness` option. I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: With pivot at individual origins, it lifts the whole edge loop.

Comment: Yes! Even thickness did the trick, with 3D cursor being at the spot it's at. Thank you!

Comment: Just found out, if i extrude the edge, then cancel extrusion and do the same trick, the even thickness setting does not function anymore?

Comment: For the lack of a faster method, you can `Mesh > Transform > Push/Pull` the loop in both axis separately. This way you can still enter exact distances.

Comment: If i extrude the edges even a tiny bit forward on the y axle and then use Alt+S + S, it works flawlessly, then move the result back where i want it. I believe it needs the normal directions of the resultant faces from the extrusion for Even thickness to work, so the faces that are created with at least a bit of movement give that normal direction.